# understanding of Array.CopyTo() and Equals()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

From the docs, my understanding of the Array.CopyTo() method is -

1. That the method produces a shallow copy of the objects into the destination array.
2. If the members of the object are a value type then they are copied, and if they are a reference type then the members refeence are copied

ICloneable.Clone() also produces a shallow copy.

So take the following code -

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.MyProperty = new object();
    var listOfA = new List<A>();
    listOfA.Add(a);
    var arrayOfA = new A[1];    
    listOfA.CopyTo(arrayOfA);
    var clonedA = a.Clone();
    listOfA[0].Equals(arrayOfA[0]); //Returns True
    clonedA.Equals(a); //Returns False

}

public class A : ICloneable
{
    public object MyProperty { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Why does the first .Equals() return true ? Should it not be False if it is a shallow copy ?

Comment: No, they are the same  `A` objects. As you said, you only copy the references. So you end up with two references pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "shallow copy" is basically a copy where the copying of individual elements is not done recursively. But what that means depends on what you're copying.

A shallow copy of a collection will have the exact same elements (reference-wise) as the original collection, but will be a distinct collection. Adding a new element to the copy won't be reflected in the source. Modifying a property of an existing element in the copy will be reflected in the source.

A shallow copy of an object will have the exact same field values (reference-wise) as the original object, but will be a distinct object.

Comment: So the Array.Copy() method is "shallow copying the list", not the items in the list. But the ICloneable.Clone() is copying the object instance. Yeah ?

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange I hope I'm not misunderstanding what you mean, but if I'm not, then yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method.

As the `CopyTo()` method copies references, `listOfA[0]` and `arrayOfA[0]` represent the same object.

But as for the `MemberwiseClone()` method, it creates a new object and does a shallow copy on the members of the original object, so the new reference doesn't refers to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st assumption is probably not right.  Array.CopyTo() does not create "shallow" copies. It will just copy the references for reference types.
[referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Array.CopyTo) look here and you will see that CopyTo comes down to the fast external method that knows nothing about objects it creates copies of (as far as I understand).